# Getting user data without callling GetUserAsync on every request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

We currently store a ClientId in the `AspnetUsers` table.  We use this to identify which user the client is logging in against, and for filtering data for by this client.

Is there a more efficient way of getting the current users clientId, in each controller without calling: `await _manager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);` In each Controller to get the clientId?  Can we use a Singleton service to set this property upon login, and inject this into our controllers?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you use `HttpContext.Session`?

Comment: @mjwills as mentioned above it is already stored in the AspnetUsers table, I do not know where to set it which is why I have asked the question

Comment: You can store it in memory, or in a more distributed fashion. The benefit of the first is speed - but it means your app will be (unless you architect it specifically) designed to work on only a single box. If you use a more distributed solution you are essentially back at square one (i.e. not much better than you have now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution would be to store the clientid as a claim so when the user logs in it will get serialized into the claimsprincipal and included in the auth cookie.

You can inherit from the default Identity ClaimsPrincipalFactory and override the CreateAsync method invoke the base class to create and then add custom claims. Then you inject your custom factory and it will be used. Then you can get the clientid from the User.Claims where User is the ClaimsPrincipal and is available in the controller actions.

By doing this you will only need to hit the db at login time to get the clientid to add as a claim. After that you can get it on every request from the claims on the User without hitting the db.

I have an example in my cloudscribe project, you can see my custom [ClaimsPrincipalFactory](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Core.Identity/SiteUserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs).

Example code:

```
public override async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(TUser user)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    }

    // base class takes care of all the default stuff like roles name id etc
    var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

    if (principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
        // add logic to get the clientid
        var clientId = yourmethod();
        var clientIdClaim = new Claim("ClientId", clientId);
        identity.AddClaim(clientIdClaim);

}
```

}

Then you could make an extension method to make it easy to get the client id claim

```
public static string GetClientId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
{
    if (principal == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
    }
    var claim = principal.FindFirst("ClientId");
    return claim != null ? claim.Value : null;
}
```

Then in the controller you can use var cleintId = User.GetClientId();

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go tonight, if I create the class that inherits from UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole> and overrides CreateAsync with the clientId claim what is the next steps to integrate this?

Comment: as mentioned just add a custom claim in the CreateAsync method, then inject it. I have added some details

Comment: This worked perfectly, I had to return the principal in the `CreateAsync` method, and register the scoped service in startup.  Thanks so much for your help.